# How to select a particular column in linux df command

Tags: shell, freebsd, linux-disk-free

I am trying to collect information on the amount of space left on different servers. So when I execute `df -k` i get output as:

```
Filesystem  1024-blocks    Used     Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/ad1s1f   125925198 2568970 113282214     2%    /builds
```

And sometimes the output comes as :

```
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
10.102.1.123:/storage/disk1/build
                     10735331328 10597534720 137796608  99% /buildbackup
```

Now I want to fetch data on the disk space available. So let me know how to fetch data from a particular column.

Answer (score 26):

You can for example say:

```
df --output=source,avail
```

Or as commented by [Tim Bunce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19703621/get-free-disk-space-with-df-to-just-display-free-space-in-kb/19703644#comment43896106_19703644), you can use `--direct` to prevent the long filesystem name make the line split in two. This will show the filesystem as `-`.

From `man df`:

> **--output[=FIELD_LIST]**
>
> use the output format defined by FIELD_LIST, or print all fields if
>   FIELD_LIST is omitted.
>
> ...
>
> FIELD_LIST is a comma-separated list of columns to be included.  Valid
>   field names  are:  'source',  'fstype',  'itotal', 'iused', 'iavail',
>   'ipcent', 'size', 'used', 'avail', 'pcent' and 'target' (see info
>   page).
>
> **--direct**
>
> show statistics for a file instead of mount point

#### Test

```
$ df --output=source,avail
Filesystem               Avail
/dev/sda7            321675536
```

Comment: When i execute the above command on my system, following message is displayed.
`# df -k --output=source,Avail

df: illegal option -- -
usage: df [-b | -g | -H | -h | -k | -m | -P] [-aciln] [-t type] [file | filesystem ...]`

Comment: Note you need to say `avail` (lowercase). If this was a type and the problem persists: what system are you working on?

Comment: The machine I am using is FreeBSD6.2

Comment: Did you try with `avail` instead of `Avail`?

Comment: Yes I tried that and the output is same as before.
`# df --output=source,avail
df: illegal option -- -
usage: df [-b | -g | -H | -h | -k | -m | -P] [-aciln] [-t type] [file | filesystem ...]
`

Comment: It's a pity, it works in my GNU du (`df --version`). Give a try with `--direct` to get a shorter output.

Comment: `df --` option is illegal on this system (FreeBSD 6.2) I think. Is there any other way to select a column based on column name?

Comment: @RamKrishna you should check `man df`, that's how I found the `--output` option.

Comment: There is no option that starts with `--` option when I do `man df` on my system

Comment: @RamKrishna ok. Then, try to find other options matching your requirements. Otherwise, you'll have to parse its output.

Comment: Actually currently i am parsing the output to get the required data. But 2 test cases are failing in that case also, since i am doing `ssh` to different versions of **FreeBSD6.2** and **Windows** system the output of `df` command is varying. The best way to get the required result looks to be obtained by fetching the data using column name. But since it looks like not possible on the FreeBSD i am using. I will have to add up code to parse and get the required output. Thanks for your help

Comment: @RamKrishna From `man df` in Free BSD (http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?df%281%29) I see you can use `df -m`, for example, to get the output in MB. This way the numbers will be smaller and you might not get a multiline output.

Answer (score 6):

fedorqui's solution is cleaner, but only works for df

A more general approach is to collapse multiple spaces to a single space using `sed 's/ \+/ /g'` or `tr -s ' '`, then use `cut` with spaces as delimiters: `cut -d" " -f 4`
So the command is:

```
df -k | tr -s ' ' | cut -d" " -f 4
```

Which results in something like this:

```
Available
26027952
854220
68376208
```

The same approach will work with other commands that output data to columns.
For instance `ls -l | tr -s ' ' | cut -d" " -f 6,7,8`
will print the time columns from `ls -l`:

```
Dec 30 17:46
Mar 1 15:33
Mar 1 14:58
Mar 2 00:00
Jan 5 14:20
Mar 1 15:33
Feb 26 11:57
Feb 4 11:11
Mar 1 14:57
```

Comment: well it only works in `df` because the question is regarding `df` :) Also, note you can squeeze spaces using `tr -s ' '`

Comment: @fedorqui I know the question was about df, and as I said, your answer is better. However, I still felt like giving a more general answer in case someone needs it.

Comment: Good point! Note, though, that the problem with `df` is that sometimes gets such a big filesystem that has to print it in two different lines, and this would be difficult to handle with `sed`.

Comment: When i execute the above command:
`df -k | sed 's/ \+/ /g' | cut -d" " -f 4`
The output is blank.
`# df -k . | sed 's/ \+/ /g' | cut -d" " -f4


# df -k . | sed 's/ \+/ /g'
`