# How to get Disk space(Avail) using 'df -h' when Filesystem is long

Tags: unix, awk, linux-disk-free

I am trying to find available disk space through console

I found `df -h | awk '$NF == "/" { print $4 }'` to get required output.

```
[root@tmpe2etstmsdc01 ~]# df -h
Filesystem                                                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_root                                542G   22G  492G   5% /
tmpfs                                                      127G     0  127G   0% /dev/shm
```

> Avail

```
[root@tmpe2etstmsdc01 ~]# df -h | awk '$NF == "/" { print $4 }'
492G
```

This gives `Use%` value when `Filesystem` is long

```
[root@ldrnr-tlsmsdc16 ~]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_root-lv_root
                   16G   16G     0 100% /
tmpfs             1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
```

Here, the command gives `Use%` instead of `Avail`

```
[root@ldrnr-tlsmsdc16 ~]# df -h | awk '$NF == "/" { print $4 }'
100%
```

How can i get `Avail` in this condition?

Comment: Does this work to you? `df --output=source,avail`? See [How to select a particular column in linux df command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28809214/1983854)

Comment: `df: unrecognized option '--output=source,avail'`
`df: unrecognized option '--output=avail'`

Comment: Must be a GNU option. It works on my `df (GNU coreutils) 8.22`. Are you in Bash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df -h | awk '$NF == "/" { if($1 ~ /^[0-9]/) print $3; else print $4 }'`

or

`df -h | awk '$NF == "/" { if($5 == "/") print $3; else print $4 }'`