# Bash script to find filesystem usage

Tags: linux, bash, shell, solaris, redhat

EDIT: Working script below

I have used this site MANY times to get answers, but I am a little stumped with this.

I am tasked with writing a script, in bash, to log into roughly 2000 Unix servers (Solaris, AIX, Linux) and check the size of OS filesystems, most notable /var /usr /opt.

I have set some variables, which may be where I am going wrong right off the bat.

1.) First I am connecting to another server that has a list of all hosts in the infrastructure. Then I parse this data with some sed commands to get a list I can use properly

1.) Then I do a ping test, to see if the server is alive. If the server is decom. The idea behind this, is if the server is not pingable, I don't want it being reported on, or any attempt to be made to connect to it, as it is just wasting time. I feel I am doing this wrong, but don't know how to do it corectly (a re-occurring theme you will here in this post lol)

If any FS is over 80% mark, then it should output to a text file with the servername, filesystem, size on one line  <== ***very important for me***

If the FS is under 80% full, then I don't want it in my output, it can me omitted completely.

I have created something that I will post below, and am hoping to get some help in figuring out where I am going wrong. I am very new to bash scripting, but have experience as a Unix admin (i have never been good at scripting).

Can anyone provide some direction and teach me where I am going wrong?

I will upload my script that i can confirm is working hopefully tomorrow. thanks everyone for your input in this!

Comment: If I run my script in a window, and tail the output file in another window, I can see in the output file that servers that are not pingable, appear in there. However, none of the servers that are a.) alive & b.) have an FS over 80% appear in there

Server     VARfs  USRfs  OPTfs
clusternode1a is offline
apache3 is offline
foaedf34 is offline
etrgpu09 is offline
fotwc31r is offline

Comment: If you need to run this in multiple operating systems, you probably can't rely on `/bin/bash` existing everywhere. Write a POSIX compatible shell script instead.

Comment: Thanks ghoti bash exists everywhere in our infrastructure.

Comment: Fair enough. Are you opposed to caching operating system information on your management machine, or is it likely that a machine might switch from one operating system to another between runs of your disk space checker?

Comment: Also, have you thought of running a tool actually designed for this sort of thing, like perhaps [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/)?

Comment: By caching this information on the management server, how will that benefit? I am not allowed under change management rules to modify any systems without a valid change record, which is a lengthy process.

Comment: You run `ssh` to determine the OS type before every check. That's wasteful of both compute and network resources. Store the info in a text file, then select your commands based on what's already known.

Comment: I agree it is wasteful in many regards but this is the way I have been taught. I am trying to learn more effective and efficient scripting. I am very new at this, so I am taking things I have learned, and applying them to new scripts that I am asked to make. Please teach me a better way :)

Comment: the only reason I do the ssh so many times is because the output of df differs from solaris, to aix, to Linux, so I have a 'custom' df command for each type of OS. I know there is better way to do this, I'mm just not sure how

Comment: *Then I do a ping test, to see if the server is alive.*  Bad idea.  There are numerous reasons why a ping to a working server can fail.  That's like testing if your car runs by trying to put gas in the tank - what if it's an electric car?

Comment: the only tool I am allowed to do this with is a shell script unfortunately.

Comment: *the only tool I am allowed to do this with is a shell script unfortunately.*  One wonders if the person(s) responsible for such an edict would require the workers putting up their houses to not use power tools - only a manual hand saw and a small 16 oz hammer - no big framing hammers, either!

Comment: What is `grep ^adm all_vms.txt | sed -i 's/^adm//g' all_vms.txt` supposed to do?

Comment: grep ^adm all_vms.txt | sed -i 's/^adm//g' all_vms.txt removed the 'adm' from the beginning of some select hostnames

the hostnames are admserver1 admserver2 admserver3 as an example
however those aren't reachable via out dns, so I have to remove the 'adm' at the beginning (i don't know why this is set up this way, it just is)

Answer (score 0):

Some trouble is here:

```
ping -c 1 -W 3 $i > /dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            echo "$i is offline" >> $LOG
    fi
```

You need a `continue` statement inside that if.  Your program isn't really treating non-pingable hosts differently, just logging they're not pingable.

Okay, now I'm looking a little deeper, and there's more naive stuff in here.  These shouldn't work:

```
SOLVARFS=$(df -h /var |cut -f5 |grep -v capacity |awk '{print $5}')
SOLUSRFS=$(df -h /usr |cut -f5 |grep -v capacity |awk '{print $5}')
SOLOPTFS=$(df -h /opt |cut -f5 |grep -v capacity |awk '{print $5}')

etc...
```

The problem with these lines is, the command substitution gets assigned to the variables before the `ssh` session happens.  So the content of each variable is the command's result on your local system, not the command itself.  Since you're doing command substitution around your `ssh` calls, it might well work just to rewrite these lines as (note the backslash escapes on `$5`):

```
SOLVARFS="df -h /var |cut -f5 |grep -v capacity |awk '{print \$5}'"
SOLUSRFS="df -h /usr |cut -f5 |grep -v capacity |awk '{print \$5}'"
SOLOPTFS="df -h /opt |cut -f5 |grep -v capacity |awk '{print \$5}'"

etc...
```

The part where you're contacting another server has some more stuff to correct.  You don't need three if statements per server, and there's no reason to echo anything to `/dev/null`.  Here's a rewrite for the SunOS section.  For each directory you're checking, it outputs the host name, the command name (so you can see which dir was being checked), and the result:

```
if [[ $UNAME = "SunOS" ]]; then
    for SSH_COMMAND in SOLVARFS SOLUSRFS SOLOPTFS ; do
        RESULT=`ssh  -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o BatchMode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=2 GSSAPIAuthentication=no -q $i ${!SSH_COMMAND}`
        if ["$RESULT" -gt 80] ; do
            echo "$i, $SSH_COMMAND, $RESULT" >> $LOG
        fi
    done
fi
```

Note that the `${!BLAH}` construction is variable indirection.  "Give me the contents of the variable named by BLAH".

Comment: *You need a `continue` statement inside that if. Your program isn't really treating non-pingable hosts differently, just logging they're not pingable.*  Not treating non-pingable hosts differently is good - just because they don't respond to pings doesn't mean they're not up.  It just means they don't respond to pings.

Comment: Thanks for the help,
is this how it should be

SOLVARFS="df -h /var |cut -f5 |grep -v capacity |awk '{print \$5}'"
SOLUSRFS="df -h /usr |cut -f5 |grep -v capacity |awk '{print \$5}'"
SOLOPTFS="df -h /opt |cut -f5 |grep -v capacity |awk '{print \$5}'"

LINVARFS="df -hP /var |awk '{ print $5 }' |grep -v Use%"
LINUSRFS="df -hP /usr |awk '{ print $5 }' |grep -v Use%"
LINOPTFS="df -hP /opt |awk '{ print $5 }' |grep -v Use%"

AIXVARFS="df /var |awk '{ print $4 }' |grep -v %Used"
AIXUSRFS="df /usr |awk '{ print $4 }' |grep -v %Used"
AIXOPTFS="df /opt |awk '{ print $4 }' |grep -v %Used"

Comment: @Andrew OP specifically wanted to treat hosts differently if they're non-pingable.  Yes, in a general sense, non-pingableness doesn't prove much.  But it's the criterion for the OP, and it's likely to be reliable within the OP's controlled network environment.

Comment: Hi Juan thanks so much
what is SSH_COMMAND
where is that defined?

Comment: It's defined in the `for` loop.  It will be set to `SOLVARFS`, `SOLUSRFS`, and `SOLOPTFS` in order (note: not set to the contents of those variables, just the variable names).  Then you can access the actual commands by `${!SSH_COMMAND}`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my "disk usage" linux script, i hope that help you.

```
#!/bin/sh

df -H | awk '{ print $5 " " $6 }' | while read output;
do
  echo $output
  usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1  )
  partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' )
  if [ $usep -ge 90 ]; then
    echo "Running out of space \"$partition ($usep%)\" on $(hostname) as on $(date)" |
     mail -s "Warning! There is no space on the disk: $usep%" root@domain.com
  fi
done
```

Comment: Note that you can use parameters to specify the columns in `df`: [How to select a particular column in linux df command](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28809214/1983854). Not in all the versions, though.

Comment: @fedorqui - note that in this case, the df command is being run on three different operating systems, so Linux-only options won't help.

Comment: @ghoti thanks for the comment. I hadn't dug very much in the question, so I wasn't aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

Your original script does a bunch of things less-than-optimally.  Rather than running an almost-identical block of code for each filesystem and each operating system, the thing to do would be to record the differences in a way that a SINGLE piece of code can iterate over all your objects, adapting as required.

Here's my take on this. Commands should appear ONCE, but

- they get run multiple times by loops, and
- they get run multiple ways using arrays.

The following script passes lint checks, but obviously this is untested, as I don't have your environment to test in.
You might still want to think about how your logging and notifications work.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Assign temp file, remove it automatically upon successful exit.
tmpfile=$(mktemp /tmp/${0##*/}.XXXX)
trap "rm '$tmpfile'" 0

#NOW=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%T")
NOW=$(date +"%F")

LOG=/usr/scripts/disk_usage/Unix_df_issues-$NOW.txt
printf '' > "$LOG"

# Use variables to refer to commonly accessed files. If you change a name, just do it once.
rawhostlist=all_vms.txt
host_os=${rawhostlist}_OS

# Commonly-used options need only be declared once. Use an array for easier management.
declare -a ssh_opts=()
ssh_opts+=(-o PasswordAuthentication=no)
ssh_opts+=(-o BatchMode=yes)
ssh_opts+=(-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no) # Eliminate prompts on new hosts
ssh_opts+=(-o ConnectTimeout=2)         # This should make your `ping` unnecessary.
ssh_opts+=(-o GSSAPIAuthentication=no)  # This is default. Do we really need it?

# Note: Associative arrays require Bash 4.x.
declare -A df_opts=(
  [SunOS]="-h"
  [Linux]="-hP"
  [AIX]=""
)
declare -A df_column=(
  [SunOS]=5
  [Linux]=5
  [AIX]=4
)

# Fetch host list from configserver, stripping /^adm/ on the remote end.
ssh "${ssh_opts[@]}" -q configserver "sed 's/^adm//' /reports/*/HOSTNAME" > "$rawhostlist"

# Confirm that our host_os cache is up to date and process any missing hosts.
awk '
  NR==FNR { h[$1]; next }   # Add everything in rawhostlist to an array...
  { delete h[$1] }          # Then remove any entries that exist in host_os.
  END {
    for (i in h) print i    # And print whatever remains.
  }' "$rawhostlist" "$host_os" |
    while read h; do
      printf '%s\t%s\n' "$h" $(ssh "$h" "${ssh_opts[@]}" -q uname -s)
    done >> "$host_os"

# Next, step through the host list and collect data.
while read host os; do
  ssh "${ssh_opts[@]}" "$host" df "${df_opts[$os]}" /var /usr /opt |
    awk -v column="${df_column[$os]}" -v host="$host" 'NR>1 { print host,$1,$column }'
  )
done < "$host_os" > "$tmpfile"

# Now that we have all our data, check for warning/critical levels.
while read host filesystem usage; do
  if [ "$usage" -gt 80 ]; then
    status="CRITICAL"
  elif [ "$usage" -gt 70 ]; then
    status="WARNING"
  else
    continue
  fi
  # Log our results to our log file, AND send them to stderr.
  printf "[%s] %s: %s:%s at %d%%\n" "$(date +"%F %T")" "$status" "$host" "$filesystem" "$usage" | tee -a "$LOG" >&2
done < "$tmpfile"

# Email and record our results.
if [ -s "$LOG" ]; then
  mail -s "Daily Unix  /var Report - $NOW" unixsystems@examplle.com < "$LOG"
  mv "$LOG" /var/log/vm_reports/
fi
```

Consider this example code. If you like the way it looks, your next task is to debug it, or open new questions for parts that you're having trouble debugging.  :-)

Comment: thanks you VERY much, I will play around with this and make necessary changes :)

I will report back