# Manipulate df output with sed

Tags: sed, linux-disk-free

I have a question about sed.

Output:

```
Filesystem              avail
rpool/ROOT/s10_u11_201704 244719726
```

Wanted information:

```
s10_u11_201704
```

I tried:

```
df -b / | sed '1d;s/.*\/\(*\ \)\ .*/\1/g'
```

The `\(*\ \)` does not work.

Comment: Note you can use `--output=source` to just print the filesystem info. See [How to select a particular column in linux df command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28809214/1983854).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `awk` :

```
df -b / |awk -F'/' 'NR>1{split($NF,a," ");print a[1]}' 
s10_u11_201704
```

Using `sed`:

```
df -b / |sed -r '1d;s|(^.*)/([^ ]+).*|\2|g'
s10_u11_201704
```

Disclaimer: `df -b` is not available in any of available distros to me.

Comment: I'm wondering because I have `df (GNU coreutils) 8.21` but no `-b` option.

Comment: I too have `df` without `-b` flag. Just mimicked for OP's understanding.

Comment: `-b` is trivial. The essence of the answer is how to extract the desired text. and  It's rightly done in all of the available answers. I think all are correct including this. On side notes, there is a change that some proprietary Linux version may have `-b` flag.

Comment: also to add, it's clearly helping OP in getting his results.

Answer (score 1):

Short ***awk*** approach:

```
df --output=source | awk -F'/' '{print $NF}'
```

---

- `--output=source` (`--output[=FIELD_LIST]`) - use the output format defined by `FIELD_LIST`
- `-F'/'` - treating `/` as field separator
- `$NF` - the last field value